# Second click on a launcher icon with more than one window open doesn't do a scale of that application

Tags: unity, 12.04, compiz, launcher

If I click an icon in the launcher with multiple windows open it doesn't show me all open windows for that application (like ctrl+w does for all open windows).

I seem to remember it working as follows for applications with multiple open windows:
1) Click on an icon in the launcher of an opened application 
2) If the application didn't have focus, it brings the most recently used application to focus (i.e. to the front)
3) If you click on the launcher icon again, or if the application already had focus you are presented with a spread/scale of all the open windows of the application and you can then select the window you want by clicking it.

Am I just wrong? How is the launcher supposed to handle multiple open windows? If I am right, how can I fix my launcher to behave like this?

I should also add that everything else works great and the ctrl+w does the scale/spread for all open windows as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug due to the last unity update from 5.10 to 5.12 a few days ago; the only solution is to downgrade unity from 5.12 back to 5.10.

Comment: Thanks Gwen. Do you have a link to the bug so I can follow it more closely?

Comment: @aspersieman This one I guess: https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-core/+bug/996604