# Clicking on active apps on unity launcher stopped working

Tags: unity, launcher

I don't know how it suddenly became this but here's what's happening right now:

e.g. I have 2 firefox windows open, so I see 2 small arrows on the left side icon of the unity launcher. Before, when I click on the firefox icon, I see 2 small windows of the firefox so I can choose which one. Now it suddenly stopped working. (super+W still works though). The bug on my system applies to all progams with multiple window instances like nautilus, terminal, etc.

Please help, I don't know what to do. I also have cairo dock, compiz, myunity installed in my 12.04. I tried searching online to no avail.

Comment: I don't really have a good answer to your question, but maybe this could be worth trying: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/unity-window-quicklists-switch-between.html

Comment: Did this ever worked for you Tim? I'm seeing the same problem right now.

Comment: Tim check this out, this worked for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/137347/second-click-on-a-launcher-icon-with-more-than-one-window-open-doesnt-do-a-scal

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the active icon once the last opened window opens, click on the icon again you will get both windows in parallel for you to choose.

Comment: Srijan, nothing happens when I do what you suggest. Before things went wrong with my unity launcher, everything worked smoothly.