# Wrong window gets focus from scale mode

Tags: unity, launcher, focus

Following [Second click on a launcher icon with more than one window open doesn't do a scale of that application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137347/second-click-on-a-launcher-icon-with-more-than-one-window-open-doesnt-do-a-scal), when I do this:

> 1. Click on an icon in the launcher of an opened application.
> 2. If the application didn't have focus, it brings the most recently used application to focus (i.e. to the front)
> 3. If you click on the launcher icon again, or if the application already had focus you are presented with a spread/scale of all the
>      open windows of the application and you can then select the window you
>      want by clicking it.

Sometimes Ubuntu brings up the wrong window. I click on window1, but window2 gets focus. It happens randomly. Seems to happen mostly (exclusively?) with LibreOffice 4.4.5.2, but I'm not sure, because of the random nature of this bug. Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS. After that, the window decoration is missing, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Updated to LibreOffice 5, error remains.

Comment: It affects other software, too, not only LibreOffice.

Comment: Pidgin IM for example.

Comment: Thunderbird, too.

Comment: Same with Chrome

Comment: Very bad with chrome.  Please has anyone found a solution